# Reference request: Dictionary learning

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, image-processing

I am interested in understanding more about sparsity coding and dictionary learning.

I am aware of the paper that describes K-SVD. Can someone please suggest a good resource for understanding more about dictionary learning and sparsity coding?

Thank you.

Comment: J. Mairal et al. “Online learning for matrix factorization and sparse coding”. In: Journal of Machine Learning Research 11 (2010). This blogpost (disclaimer: i wrote it) is also worth reading http://dohmatob.github.io/research/2016/10/07/ssodl.html.